# React Native handle 2 different tokens for ios and android

Tags: react-native, oauth, github-api

I'm using this lib : [react-native-oauth](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth).

I take the Github example where I have to create 2 different apps into the developper account. So I have 2 different tokens.

How can I manage this config:

```
const config =  {
  github: {
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
  }
}
```

To work on both ios/android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
const config =  {
let token = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "IOS TOKEN" : "Android Token";
github: {
   client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
   client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
  }
}
```